# How to pass datetime value to the service

Tags: wcf

I've tried various options, but am not able to figure out how to pass the date time value to the service call:

```
http://localhost:64550/LimCmsDataService.svc/Listing?id='1,2,3,4'&startDate=datetime'2000-12-12T12:00%22'
http://localhost:64550/LimCmsDataService.svc/Listing?id='1,2,3,4'&startDate='2000-12-12T12:00%22'
```

Can some one help me, with how to pass the startDate to the Listing service:

```
public int Listing(int? id,DateTime? startDate)
{
            CurrentDataSource.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            return this.CurrentDataSource.Listing(id,startDate);
}
```

Comment: WCF can't be consumed like that as far as I know. Build client application, add Service Reference and consume the service from within your code.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess I'd say you don't need the single quotes.  Also, in your example Uris, your value for `id` isn't an `int` - so I'd not expect the requests to work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the issues Dan has pointed out, consider changing the input format.

Even if you manage to make it work, Dates are prone to locale-specific confusions when passed  through URL. To make it less confusing for users, it is better to accept as 3 parameters (startDay, startMonth, startYear)